# Where magic database for filetypes

Tags: file

Where one can download or obtain source of magic database for libmagic (a `file` command). I have compiled version in `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc` but can not find original source file. (Ideally I would like to know where on the Internet is original, NOT system/distribution-specific format of such file.)

I was unable to find it ever after hours of googling.

Thanks

Comment: libmagic is not "a `file` command". It is a library used _by_ the `file` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the sources for the `file` command ([github](https://github.com/file/file); [ftp](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/)). Specifically, in the "magic" subdirectory. There is not a single source file; the database is compiled from multiple sources.

("libmagic" is part of the `file` package).

Answer (score 1):

The `file` utility has a GitHub repository at https://github.com/file/file and a homepage at http://www.darwinsys.com/file/

I imagine that any distribution using these sources do so in a modified form.  It might even be that the local `file` utility and the associated `libmagic` library has diverged *significantly* from the above sources.

On OpenBSD systems, the `libmagic` library is available as a port. It will pull the sources from an FTP site associated with the GitHub repository above.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can get exact source code for libmagic (with patches, if any) with the following command:

```
apt-get source libmagic-dev
```

It will download the source to the current directory.

If you didn't know the package name, you could use apt-file to find out:

```
apt-file search libmagic.so
```

You might need to install `apt-file` using

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```